# OCaml: problem with type constructor escaping its scope

Tags: types, ocaml

Here is the code:

```
module type S = sig
  type t
  val do_it: t -> int -> t
end

let rec foo (type a) (module Foo:S with type t=a) (i:int) (x:a) = 
  if i=0 then x
  else foo (i-1) (Foo.do_it x i)
```

I get this type error (at line 8, characters 17-32):

```
Error: This expression has type a but an expression was expected of type 'a
       The type constructor a would escape its scope
```

Which is unexpected since the type constructor `a` is still in its scope. I expect function foo to have the following type:

```
foo: (module S with type t = 'a) -> int -> 'a -> 'a
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I don't understand that syntax but your code can be simplified to `let rec foo (type a) (x:a) = foo x` (which still throws the same error).

Comment: (Your recursive call to `foo` is missing the module parameter in the code you give here. I assume this is just a transcription error.)

Comment: @JeffreyScofield From what I know, the module parameter can be elided in the recursive call. But even if I explicitly give it as `(module Foo:S with type t=a)`, I still get the same type error, this time at the location of this module parameter.

Comment: Yes, this is not the basic problem, it's just an observation. When I leave out the module parameter I get a type error about it. I don't see why it would be legitimate to elide it, but I learn new things about OCaml all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is polymorphic recursion: the function `foo` cannot be polymorphic in its body without explicit annotation. When writing

```
let rec foo (type a) (module Foo:S with type t=a) (i:int) (x:a) = 
  if i=0 then x
  else foo (module Foo:S with type t = a) (i-1) (Foo.do_it x i)
```

since the function `foo` is not polymorphic in its definition, it cannot reuse the locally abstract type `type a` which has been introduced after its own definition.

One way to circumvent this issue is to introduce the recursive function after the locally abstract type:

```
let foo (type a) =
  let rec foo (module Foo:S with type t=a) (i:int) (x:a) = 
  if i=0 then x
  else foo (module Foo) (i-1) (Foo.do_it x i) in
  foo
```

A more classical solution is to add an explicit universal quantification to the locally abstract type `a`:

```
let rec foo: type a. (module S with type t=a) -> int -> a -> a =
fun (module Foo) i x ->
  if i=0 then x
  else foo (module Foo) (i-1) (Foo.do_it x i)
```

Comment: Great explanation, thanks! I was assuming that `type a` parameter to `foo` universally quantifies `a`. Clearly it doesn't. This leads to a followup question: what is the semantics of `type a` when it occurs as a function parameter? How does type inference treat such parameters? (Maybe this deserves to be a separate question; I'm not sure.)

Comment: When you write `fun (type a) -> fun x -> ..` (or the shortcut version `f (type a) x = ...`), the type `a` behaves as a standard abstract type (aka a type defined with just `type a`) on the right hand side of `fun (type a)` but it cannot escape from this right hand side. This has three major use cases. First, unifying `a` with another type is an error which can be useful when debugging a type error. Second, this type `a` can be used in local module definition or a first-class module constraints. And finally, since this type is abstract, it can be refined when pattern matching a GADT.